# SecurityContext doesn't work with @RolesAllowed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, tomcat7, jax-rs

I'm currently creating a backend server using Jersey 2.5.1 in a Tomcat 7. For the security I'm using the `@RolesAllowed`, `@PermitAll` etc. annotations, and I have created my custom `ContainerRequestFilter` and `SecurityContext`.

My problem is that when my `@RolesAllowed` annotated resource is requested it always denies permission, even if I force my `isUserInRole(role)` method to return `true`. However, my `filter` method gets called. Do you have any suggestions? I'll paste some relevant code below.

My `ContainerRequestFilter` implementation:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException
    {
        request.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer());
    }
}
```

My `SecurityContext` implementation:

```
public class Authorizer implements SecurityContext
{

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

My resource:

```
@Path("/secure")
public class TestSecureResource {

    @GET
    @PermitAll
    @Path("/nonsec_test/{text}")
    public Response nonSecureTest(
            @PathParam("text") String text){

        return Response.status(200).entity(text).build();
    }

    @GET
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    @Path("/sec_test/{text}")
    public Response secureTest(
            @PathParam("text") String text){

        return Response.status(200).entity(text).build();
    }
}
```

My `ResourceConfig`:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        super(TestSecureResource.class);
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        register(AuthorizationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Relevant parts of my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>pkg.backend</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>pkg.backend.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

In this specific case, my access to `secureTest` is always denied. To clarify things; I'm getting HTTP status code 403 - Forbidden.

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have your `AuthorizationFilter` either registered in your `MyApplication` (see [Registering Resources and Providers in Jersey 2](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/)) or annotated with [@Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers.html) (to make it discoverable by package scanning).

In order to use security annotations (package `javax.annotation.security`) to restrict access to your resources you need to register [RolesAllowedDynamicFeature](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.html).

#### EDIT 1

Your `AuthorizationFilter` has to be also annotated with `@PreMatching` which means that the filter is invoked before matching phase (uri -> resource). Otherwise filters registered by `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` (invoked during this phase) won't see the custom `SecurityContext`.

#### EDIT 2

Jersey User Guide - [Authorization - securing resources](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12428)

Comment: Thanks for that great reply. I noticed that I forgot to paste the MyApplcation that extends ResourceConfig in the question, will add it in an edit.. I had registered both the AuthorizationFilter and the RolesAllowedDynamicFeature. Also added the @Provided now, but I'm still unable to trigger the method in my SecurityContext. Great link btw, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: My apologies, forgot about `@PreMatching`. Added Edit 1.

Answer (score 1):

In a real application, defining your own `ResourceConfig` means you have to edit it every time you add a new resource (class).

A nice way to avoid that problem is to register the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` class in an `<init-param>` to the `<servlet>` in your `web.xml` like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>your_servelet_name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

If you do that then you can put this  in to dynamically register all resources in particular  packages:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.your-domain.your-packages-1,com.your-domain.your-packages-2</param-value>
    </init-param>
```